# what is mean "v.template is<T>()" in this c++ prog?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

[c++ code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PK5OW.jpg)

```
template <typename F, typename V, typename R, typename T, typename... Types>
struct dispatcher<F, V, R, T, Types...>
{
    VARIANT_INLINE static R apply_const(V const& v, F&& f)
    {
        if (v.template is<T>())
        {
            return f(unwrapper<T>::apply_const(v.template get_unchecked<T>()));
        }
        else
        {
            return dispatcher<F, V, R, Types...>::apply_const(v, std::forward<F>(f));
        }
    }

    VARIANT_INLINE static R apply(V& v, F&& f)
    {
        if (v.template is<T>())
        {
            return f(unwrapper<T>::apply(v.template get_unchecked<T>()));
        }
        else
        {
            return dispatcher<F, V, R, Types...>::apply(v, std::forward<F>(f));
        }
    }
};
```

what is mean `v.template is<T>()` in this c++ prog?
i cannot find any "is" function, this `v.template is<T>()` is system inner function or keyword with `v.template get_unchecked<T>()`.

Comment: Apparently, whichever type `dispatcher` is going to be instantiated with, is expected to provide a member function template named `is`.

Comment: The code seems to come [from here](https://github.com/mapbox/variant/blob/master/include/mapbox/variant.hpp). Class `variant` in that file does have a member function template named `is`, as well as one named `get_unchecked`. Where were you looking for it, that you failed to find it?

Comment: If the question is about the syntax `.template`, see [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)